# RegExp matching url

Tags: regex

I have the current url:

```
ristoranti/location/latvia/riga/other-tag
```

I need a regexp that do not get the url if has the `location` segment

Here what I tried:

```
ristoranti/(?!location$).*)?(.+?)/(.+?)
```

Example url I need to get:

```
ristoranti/latvia/riga/other-tag
```

I'm not so good with regexp but if I'm right the first segment shoulg get all but `location`, am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: You need to remove `/location/` from the string using a simple string operation. Or use two capturing groups, like `(ristoranti/)[^/]*/(.+?)` and replace with `$1$2`.

Comment: I can't remove `/location/` with any operation

Comment: Unclear question. Your regex contains `location`, but the result what you want contains `latvia`. Something went wrong. I suggest to providing some cases to match with the regex and the ouput what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is presence of `$` in your negative lookahead that will fail to stop `ristoranti/location/latvia/riga/other-tag` from matching because your URL is not really ending with `location`. You should replace it by

```
(?!location/)
```

which will fail the match when URL has `location/` ahead.

Also use `^` at the start. So your final regex should be:

```
^ristoranti/(?!location/)([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YO7v0m/2)